# Is it possible to reuse a content sheme URI

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

When opening a file from a file explorer I get a content scheme URI like following:

```
content://com.asus.filemanager.OpenFileProvider/file/sdcard/backups/apps/testfile.apk
```

I then make a temporary copy of the file using the content resolver using something like following:

```
File tempFile = getFileFromContentUri(getContext(), mUri, null);
```

After the app processed tempFile this file gets deleted. The problem is now that I want to forward mUri to another activity with following code, but I am getting a security exception while doing so, so it seems that the URI can only be used once, is this right?:

```
        private forwardFile(Uri fileUri) {
            final Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
            Uri uri;
            if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equals(fileUri.getScheme())) {
                uri = new Uri.Builder()
                        .path(fileUri.getPath())
                        .authority(fileUri.getAuthority())
                        .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)
                        .build();
            }
            installIntent.setData(uri);
            installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            context.startActivity(installIntent);
       }
```

Is there the possibility to reuse the uri or a workaorund that you can see? I'm not seeing a way I can handle this, e.g. I must delete the temp file, but if I forward the copied file instead of the original URI I don't get a callback so I wouldn't know when to delete the copied file.

And here the exception I am getting:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Uid 10165 does not have permission to uri 0 @ content://com.asus.filemanager.OpenFileProvider/file/sdcard/backups/apps/testfile.apk
```

Comment: `I want to forward mUri`. I don't see an `mUri`.

Comment: `fileUri.getScheme()`. What is `fileUri`?

Comment: `so it seems that the URI can only be used once`. No you can use it as often as you want in the same activity. Have a look at and google `context.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission()` for using after a restart of your app.  To transfer the permission to a diffrent activity is something else.

Comment: as you can see I am starting another activity, so it is not the same, it could be any activity registered for defined intent so I must transfer the permission I guess? how does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Only if the serving app defines a persistent permission and the client calls context.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission() this may work, but I am also not sure.

Answer (score -1):

You got the permission for:

```
content://com.asus.filemanager.OpenFileProvider/file/sdcard/backups/apps/testfile.apk
```

No wonder that you got a `java.lang.SecurityException`: using a completely different (and non existing) file:

```
content://com.asus.filemanager.OpenFileProvider/file/sdcard/Download/testfile.apk
```

Comment: Come on, the log was only testing it with another file

Comment: Come on... cant you write a decent post? How dare you mark answer as negative!